# vue router 404 fallback for chunk missing after new release

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

We have a vue2 app.

It has quite a few pages.

On prod release, all the output is hashed chunks as expected.

The client for reasons out of our control does not want to use a PWA.

**There is an issue:**

1. Send out a new release to the site, each user loading the url will get the new code. All good.
2. Now send out another new release and all the file hashes change, for someone already on the site if they now click a link on the app but without loading the fresh index... the vue router silently fails and to the user nothing happens.

To be precise...

1. User loads index which loads the SPA which lazy loads chunks on demand... eg dashboard.xyzsd.js
2. We release the code base, and the user still has the previous app in memory, so clicking a link to the dashboard it tries to load dashboard.xyzsd.js which no longer exists.

What we would like to happen here is the app catches the error and instead does a full page reload to the human friendly link of "/dashboard"

Reading the docs, https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html#navigationfailuretype

I cannot see a simple fallback catch all for the vue-router. There are 100's of links all over the site, and we simply cannot be going to each link and wrapping them in a try catch.

We were expecting to find a catch all for the vue router... has anyone seen this?